# Error: The deployment target requir Qt libs, but init qmake is failed. (CQtDeployer)

Tags: qt, deployment, terminal, qml, ubuntu-18.04

i am try to use CQtDeployer.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and QT 5.9.5.

I want to run this on terminal:

```
cqtdeployer -bin MY_APP_NAME_IN_RELEASE_FOLDER -qmake /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake
```

Note:

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -> FROM QT CREATOR -> options -> qt versions -> autodetected qt 5.9.5 -> qmake locations
```

Result:

```
Info: Deploy ...
Info: flag targetDir not used. use default target dir :/root/Masaüstü/RELEASE/DistributionKit
Error: The deployment target requir Qt libs, but init qmake is failed.
Error: deploy is failed!
```

Note2:

```
root@ubuntu-pc:~/DEPLOY_TEST_1# qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

And the solution:

> Blockquote
>   Solution 1
>   As a workaround, uninstall the snap version of cqtdeployer and install cqtdeployer from the installer.

Solution 2
Install Qt from an official source in user space.

If you are unable to use the GUI, use the console utility to install Qt

> Blockquote

Solution from : https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/issues/373#issuecomment-637762214